# How to solve no value in select when ngModel changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, select, binding

A project contains a component and a service.

Component injects the service and uses services field filter. There is a select in the components hmtl. [(ngModel)] of the select is binded to filter.sizes.width.

The component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-facet-sizes-static',
  templateUrl: './facet-sizes-static.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./facet-sizes-static.component.scss']
})
export class FacetSizesStaticComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private Search: SearchService
  ) {
    this.filter = Search.filter;
  }

  clearFilter() {
    this.filter.sizes.width = 0;
  }
}
```

Its template:

```
<div (click)="clearFilter()"></div>


<!-- Comment_01 -->
{{filter.sizes.width}}

<div *ngIf="filter.sizes">
    <select name="width"
            [(ngModel)]="filter.sizes.width">
        <option [ngValue]="null">~</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of facet.sizes[0].parts.width; let x = index" 
                [ngValue]=item>
            {{ item }} 
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The service:

```
export class SearchService {

  filter: SearchServiceFilter = null;

  constructor() {
  this.filter = {
      sizes: {
        width: 0
      },
    };
  }

}
```

When I change option in select it changes filter.sizes.width as I exapt. But there are two problems:

1. when component is inited there is no value in the select but filter.sizes.width has 0 value. I can check it watching the string {{filter.sizes.width}} under Comment_01
2. when the method clearFilter() changes filter.sizes.width there is becomes again no value in the select.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your facet.sizes[0].parts.width array does not contain a value === 0. I see your option with a value of null, but null does not equal 0 and will not be selected. If you add an option with a value === 0; it should select it.